# Order of transaction Signing

Tags: transactions, signing

Does the order of signers keys signing a transaction matter?

While going through the versioned transaction source code, `signer_keys` and `expected_signer_keys` vectors are being compared and this throws a `KeypairPubkeyMismatch` if the order of keys signing the transaction does not match.

```
impl VersionedTransaction {
    /// Signs a versioned message and if successful, returns a signed
    /// transaction.
    pub fn try_new<T: Signers>(
        message: VersionedMessage,
        keypairs: &T,
    ) -> std::result::Result<Self, SignerError> {
        let static_account_keys = message.static_account_keys();
        if static_account_keys.len() < message.header().num_required_signatures as usize {
            return Err(SignerError::InvalidInput("invalid message".to_string()));
        }

        let signer_keys = keypairs.pubkeys();
        let expected_signer_keys =
            &static_account_keys[0..message.header().num_required_signatures as usize];
        ...
        if signer_keys != expected_signer_keys {
            return Err(SignerError::KeypairPubkeyMismatch);
        }
```

More at [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/7e4397204ae76088d3ac2fcf4f8e5d71fceda03d/sdk/src/transaction/versioned/mod.rs#L84)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order does matter. The first signer included in the array of signers is always the one responsible for paying the transactions fees.